# Yii2 Codeception Run with Coverage in Docker container using PhpStorm - error: No code coverage driver available

Tags: phpstorm, code-coverage, yii2-advanced-app, functional-testing, codeception

I have built a Yii2 advanced application that is running in a Docker container.

I have installed Docker as a service in PhpStorm, So I don't need to use another console to access my containers.

I have created a Run/debug configurations to execute Codeception tests within PhpStorm that are working perfectly.

[image]

[image]

But When I click on the "Shield" button (Run with coverage)

[image]

I receive an error message:('No code coverage driver available')
[image]

But when I execute this command from inside the backend container:

```
codecept run --coverage --coverage-xml --coverage-html
```

Everything is working fine.
[image]

I have read a lot on that topic, but everybody seems to point in the direction of Xdebug, that might not be working.  As you will be able to see in my config files, I'm using **yiisoftware/yii2-php:7.2-apache** image which contains xdebug and that I also enable it using environment variables. To prove that, I'm also able to run a debug session in PhpStorm.

What I don't understand is that this 'Run With Coverage' command is executing inside the same backend container and should then see that xdebug is active...

```
[docker-compose://[C:\Users\Francois\Projects\tadv\docker-compose.yml]:backend/]:php /opt/.phpstorm_helpers/codeception.php run --report -o "reporters: report: PhpStorm_Codeception_ReportPrinter" --no-interaction --coverage-xml /opt/phpstorm-coverage/tadv$Codeception_BE_All.xml --quiet -c /app/backend/codeception.yml
```

There is probably something that I'm missing.
Any help would be appreciated.

Here are my configuration files:

```
backend/docker-compose file
------------------------
version: '3.2'

services:

  frontend:
    build: frontend
    ports:
      - 20080:80
    volumes:
      # Re-use local composer cache via host-volume
      - ~/.composer-docker/cache:/root/.composer/cache:delegated
      # Mount source-code for development
      - ./:/app
    environment:
      # When using Hyper-V
      XDEBUG_CONFIG: remote_host=host.docker.internal remote_log=/tmp/xdebug.log
      PHP_ENABLE_XDEBUG: 1

  backend:
    build: backend
    ports:
      - 21080:80
    volumes:
      # Re-use local composer cache via host-volume
      - ~/.composer-docker/cache:/root/.composer/cache:delegated
      # Mount source-code for development
      - ./:/app
    environment:
      # When using Hyper-V
      XDEBUG_CONFIG: remote_host=host.docker.internal remote_log=/tmp/xdebug.log
      # When using VirtualBox
      #XDEBUG_CONFIG: "remote_host=10.0.2.2 remote_port=9000 "
      PHP_ENABLE_XDEBUG: 1
```

```
backend/Dockerfile
------------------------
FROM yiisoftware/yii2-php:7.2-apache

# Change document root for Apache
RUN sed -i -e 's|/app/web|/app/backend/web|g' /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
```

```
Global codeception file
------------------------
# global codeception file to run tests from all apps
include:
    - common
    - frontend
    - backend
paths:
    log: console/runtime/logs
settings:
    colors: true
```

```
backend/codeception file
------------------------
namespace: backend\tests
actor_suffix: Tester
paths:
    tests: tests
    output: tests/_output
    data: tests/_data
    support: tests/_support
coverage:
    enabled: true
    remote: true
    include:
        - models/*
        - controllers/*
    exclude:
        - assets/*
        - config/*
        - runtime/*
        - views/*
        - web/*
        - tests/*
bootstrap: _bootstrap.php
settings:
    colors: true
    memory_limit: 1024M
modules:
    config:
        Yii2:
            configFile: 'config/codeception-local.php'
```

```
XDebug as found in my container php.ini
------------------------
root@b61903ccfbd7:/app# php -i | grep 'XDEBUG'

PHP_ENABLE_XDEBUG => 1
XDEBUG_CONFIG => remote_host=host.docker.internal remote_log=/tmp/xdebug.log
VERSION_XDEBUG => 2.8.1
$_SERVER['PHP_ENABLE_XDEBUG'] => 1
$_SERVER['XDEBUG_CONFIG'] => remote_host=host.docker.internal remote_log=/tmp/xdebug.log
$_SERVER['VERSION_XDEBUG'] => 2.8.1
$_ENV['PHP_ENABLE_XDEBUG'] => 1
$_ENV['XDEBUG_CONFIG'] => remote_host=host.docker.internal remote_log=/tmp/xdebug.log
$_ENV['VERSION_XDEBUG'] => 2.8.1
```

Comment: Probably extended IDE logs could tell more? You may enable these by adding the following line to the "Help > Debug log settings:
#com.jetbrains.php

After reproducing the error, log can be checked via "Help > Show log in.."

Is there anything interesting?